# Meu banco de dados está dando erro(1050) no id

Tags: mysql

create database torneio
default character set utf8
default collate utf8_general_ci;

create table jogador (
id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
id_clube smallint NOT NULL,
nome varchar(30) NOT NULL,
numero tinyint(3) NOT NULL ,
posicao varchar(30) NOT NULL
)

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)). Se a solução for muito simples ainda é possível que alguém o faça nos comentários.

Answer (score -2):

A síntaxe para criação da tabela está correta. Consegui realizar a criação num MySQL de teste que tenho aqui. Onde exatamente está dando erro?

Qualquer coisa, tente assim:

```
CREATE TABLE `jogador` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `id_clube` smallint NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `numero` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `posicao` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: Sempre dá erro ao executar. Tentei colocar desse jeito porém deu o seguinte erro:Error code: 1273. Unknown collation: 'utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci'

Comment: Entendo. Você está tentando incluir direto por alguma ferramenta, por exemplo, um Wrokbench? Quanto ao erro que deu no código que eu enviei, tente assim:

`CREATE TABLE `jogador` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `id_clube` smallint NOT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `numero` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `posicao` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) `

Comment: Conseguiu criar sua tabela @LeoDev ?